# Login to website from WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, account

How can I make a winform application which enables me to log in to a website from my desktop?

Comment: This depends on the website itself. This could be done in many ways (HTTP, Socket connections, API..etc).

Comment: What is the easiest way, I just want to send the provided info to the same destination as it would when logging in through the webpage

Comment: As @LordCover has mentioned, it depends on the target website. One easy solution would be to create a WebRequest and POST it to whereever the website's login page POST's the login details.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways

1- Use WebBrowser Control and Navigate to your website , and do login into your web site.

2- Use HttpWebRequest class and use Credentials property

easiest way is option no 1